# Rails 3.1: Is it possible to run UNICORN sever on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

Just wanted to know is it possible to use unicorn as dev web server on MS Windows machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicorn use much of features provided by Unix/Unix-style kernels.

Therefore - it's not possible.